# Android - Preference OnPreferenceClick is never called

Tags: java, android, preference, onpreferenceclicklistener

I really need some help here! Logcat doesn't give out any errors, no errors in code and still nothing is happening. I got 2 normal Preferences "ueber", which works anytime I click it and "update", which is never called. I know that because i copied the exact code of "ueber" to "update" and still nothing was happening... I'm already sitting 2 weaks on that and you guys are my last hope!

***preferencesettings2.xml***

```
<PreferenceScreen>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Info">
    <Preference
        android:key="update"
        android:title="Update"
        android:summary="Check for updates"/>
    <Preference 
        android:key="about"
        android:title="About"
        android:summary="Shows information"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

***Preferencesettings2.java***

`public class Preferencesettings2 extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceClickListener {
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferencesettings2);

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    if(preference.getKey().equals("update")){
        download();
    }else if(preference.getKey().equals("about")){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Preferencesettings2.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("about");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("About");
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }

        });
         alertDialogBuilder.show();
    }
    return true;
}`

Answer (score 2):

Try locating the preference with `findPreference` and calling `setOnPreferenceClickListener`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferencesettings2);
    findPreference("about").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    findPreference("update").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
}
```